# How to combine multiple fields into array in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB 3.2 and am trying figure out if there is a way to combine mutiple fields into an array field. For example, let's say I have a query that looks like this:

```
db.companies.find({},
{
  _id: 0,
  CompanyName: 1,
  CompanyAlias1: 1,
  CompanyAlias2: 1,
  CompanyAlias3: 1,
  CompanyAlias4: 1
}).limit(4);
```

The above query returns the following documents:

```
{ "CompanyName" : "Company ABC", "CompanyAlias1" : "Company ABC, Inc." }
{ "CompanyName" : "ACME Corp.", "CompanyAlias1" : "ACME Corporation", "CompanyAlias2" : "Coyote Lawncare" }
{ "CompanyName" : "Green Tea Sippers" }
{ "CompanyName" : "JS Inc", "CompanyAlias1" : "John Smith Ent", "CompanyAlias2" : "DBA J Smith", "CompanyAlias3" : "Mr. J Tree Climbing", "CompanyAlias4" : "Another crazy name", "CompanyAlias5" : "last one" }
```

Instead, I would like the enumerated CompanyAlias[x] fields to be combined into an array named CompanyAliases. So the results should look like this:

```
{ "CompanyName" : "Company ABC", "CompanyAliases" : [{ "Alias" : "Company ABC, Inc."} ]}
{ "CompanyName" : "ACME Corp.", "CompanyAliases" : [{ "Alias" : "ACME Corporation"}, { "Alias" : "Coyote Lawncare"} ]}
{ "CompanyName" : "Green Tea Sippers" }
{ "CompanyName" : "JS Inc", "CompanyAliases" : [{"Alias" : "John Smith Ent"}, {"Alias" : "DBA J Smith"}, {"Alias" : "Mr. J Tree Climbing"}, {"Alias" : "Another crazy name"}, {"Alias" : "last one"}]}
```

I am very new to MongoDB, and coming from the RDBMS world I'm still getting my mind wrapped around many of its concepts. Any insights on how I could achieve the above example are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of maximum aliases, you can do it explicitly:

```
db.companies.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                _id: '$_id',
                CompanyName: '$CompanyName'
            },
            CompanyAlias1: {
                $push: {
                    Alias: '$CompanyAlias1'
                }
            },
            CompanyAlias2: {
                $push: {
                    Alias: '$CompanyAlias2'
                }
            },
            CompanyAlias3: {
                $push: {
                    Alias: '$CompanyAlias3'
                }
            },
            CompanyAlias4: {
                $push: {
                    Alias: '$CompanyAlias4'
                }
            },
            CompanyAlias5: {
                $push: {
                    Alias: '$CompanyAlias5'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            CompanyName: '$_id.CompanyName',
            CompanyAliases: {
                $setUnion: ['$CompanyAlias1', '$CompanyAlias2', '$CompanyAlias3', '$CompanyAlias4', '$CompanyAlias5']
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            CompanyName: 1,
            CompanyAliases: {
                $filter: {
                    input: '$CompanyAliases',
                    as: 'alias',
                    cond: {
                        $ne: ['$$alias', {}]
                    }
            }
            }
        }
    }
])
```